# use of undeclared crate or module in rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

When I compile the rust project using `cargo build`(rust 1.54):

```
~/Documents/GitHub/hello-world on  master! ⌚ 19:31:43
$ cargo build                                                                                                                                                          ‹ruby-2.7.2›
   Compiling hello-world v0.1.0 (/Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/hello-world)
error[E0432]: unresolved import `ini`
 --> src/main.rs:2:5
  |
2 | use ini::Properties;
  |     ^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `ini`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
error: could not compile `hello-world`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
(base)
```

this is my `main.rs`:

```
use ini::Properties;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

and this is my `Cargo.toml`:

```toml
[package]
name = "hello-world"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
rust-ini = { version = "0.17.0", optional = true }
```

I can go to the ini difinition in IntellJ Idea Rust IDE, why still tell me this error? what should I do to fix it? I have already searching from internet but find no clue.

Comment: `rust-ini` is listed as optional, so you need to either enable it via `--features` or make it not optional.

Comment: @E_net4theflagger: Or specify `default-features`...